# Is it considered a bad practice to put all enum types within an application in a header file with other constants?

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are some enum types in my iOS objective-C app that are used in different classes, for them I guess its fine to put them in a constants.h file, but what about others that are not necessarily used in multiple classes? would it be considered a bad practice?

Comment: There is no "one size fits all" rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While sapi's answer isn't wrong, here's what I have a tendency to do...

A group of constants that are used across multiple files will go into a file.  Let's say all my `Foo` constants go in `FooConstants.h`.

Now another group, say the `Bar` constants, they'll all go in `BarConstants.h`.

These files will have constants, enums, and protocol definitions in them.

In the files that need the `Foo` constants only, I'll import `FooConstants.h`.

In the files that need the `Bar` constants only, I'll import `BarConstants.h`.

And depending on the project, I may have just 1 of these files, or I may have 10 or more.  Usually I'll have a file called `SegueNames.h`, where all of my storyboard segue identifiers are created as constants and put in this file so I never misspell a segue name.  I'll also usually have `DefaultsKeys.h`, where I keep the keys to anything I'm putting in `NSUserDefaults`.

And then I started realizing every now and then, I might have a file that uses 6 of these constants files, so I started creating `Constants.h`.

`Constants.h` has nothing in it except importing all the other constants files.  This cleans up the top of some of my files.

But at the end of the day, I do still keep the constants organized in their own files with some sort of grouping putting common constants together.  And as sapi points out, any constant that is used only in a single file should be defined within that file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is bad practice.

If you place all of your constants, including enums, into the one file, then importing that file becomes necessary whenever you want to reuse part of your code.

A better practice would be to group your constants by function (at whatever level is appropriate for your app), and to include constants used only in a single class in the class file itself or, if you must, in a separate header.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answers @sapi, so to conclude,I'm ok having those constants, keys or enum types in a constants.h file only when they will be use in multiple classes, otherwise I should put them within the one class where they are used, correct?

Comment: There's an in between approach also, @Andrespch.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. How well organized are your classes? If it's a bit of a mess, it doesn't hurt to start with an Errors.h/m file where you define your error codes as enums in the .h file and your error domains as NSStrings in the .m file (with corresponding `extern NSString * const` in your .h file).

If your organization is a bit better, then you've divided your classes into modules and each module has an entry point, where you should be defining these things. The result doesn't change though: Error header for enum values and extern declarations, error implementation for extern assignments.

All my error declaration files look like this:

```
// ErrorFile.h
typedef enum {
    ModuleErrorOne = 1,
    ModuleErrorTwo,
    ModuleErrorThree
} ModuleError;

extern NSString * const ModuleErrorDomain;

// ErrorFile.m
NSString * const ModuleErrorDomain = @"ModuleErrorDomain";
```

You can stick it in your pre-compiled header for a compilation speed boost.

EDIT: Thanks for the comments nhgrif and GraniteRobert, they've improved my answer.

Comment: Not using `NS_ENUM`?  Not prefixing constants with a k?  And recommending stuffing it into `.pch` to make it even more global and giving you literally no control over what files it shows up in?  Also.... you're declaring your `const` completely wrong... and then not even continuing to define it as a const in the .m....

Comment: You know though that `NSString const *` isn't right though, right?  You don't need to declare the `NSString` as const (which is what you're doing)... it's an immutable object.  You need the pointer to the object to be const.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55217/36366

Comment: @nhgrif You are correct, it should be `NString * const`.

Comment: @nhgrif Give me some time to finish editing before responding, wish I could have just messaged you directly :-)

Comment: @Tony: Everybody's an idiot sometimes. The definition in the .m file should get the same `const` as the declaration in the .h file. That way when someone has an idiot moment, the compiler will catch the mistake.